# Connect Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio Model to Streamlit

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-machine-learning-service, streamlit, mlops

I'm building a simple web from streamlit that connects with a machine learning model from Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studion (non-classic) and I'm new to both azure and streamlit.

I have trained the model that I'm going to use and wondering how do I connect this model to the web. What are the next things that I need to do to be able to do that? What are some Azure resources that I need to use?

Here is the latest progress of my work
[image: Model from Azure Machine Learning Studio]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to deploy your model as a stand-alone REST API that your application will consume.

Here is the Azure documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-and-where?view=azureml-api-1&tabs=azcli